# Editting Vim Configurations

Tags: linux, vim, ssh

I have a very simple and easy question, but I do not know how to do it.  I am on a ubuntu machine, logged in via ssh.  I want to edit my vim so that I dont have to keep typing *:set number* or *:colorscheme elflord*.  I would like it to remember that information.  When browsing around I found out that I need to change a .vimrc file, and that is supposedly located in my home directory, however it is not, and furthermore #locate .vimrc does not locate anything.  Can any help me with finding where this file is and editing the above commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `~/.vimrc` with the lines you want in it:

```
set number
colorscheme elflord
```

See `:help vimrc` and `:help vimrc-intro` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Your global `vimrc` is located in `/etc/vim` you can just create a `.vimrc` in your home directory. This question however should be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: The question is perfectly appropriate here, since vim is a software tool commonly used by programmers (see the FAQ), even though it's a very very basic vim question. Sure, it'd be answered on those other sites too, but it's within the scope of SO.

Answer (score 1):

You may edit it from anywhere with this command:

`:e $MYVIMRC`

If the file doesn't exist, just create it in ~/.vimrc